# SQL select only duplicates with pattern matching

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb, pattern-matching

**With given:** 5.5.68-MariaDB OR Mysql 8.0,
there are rows with possible duplicated OrderIDs within `comments` rows...
OrderIDs could be found by pattern matching only from strings in a form like in the tables below, comment column.

**a task**: via pattern matching, fetch order_id's and find duplicates only.
/And yes, I read MySQL manuals (^_^)/

E.g.

| id | datetime | amount | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 2023-04-23, 11:46:04 | 160 | DEBIT Order#:11985, OrderUsername: chana |
| 11112 | 2023-04-23, 11:46:04 | -160 | CREDIT Order#:11985, OrderUsername: chana |
| 11113 | 2023-04-23, 11:46:04 | -120 | CREDIT Order#:17738, OrderUsername: demi |

There's a need to fetch in a form like

| id | datetime | amount | comment | order_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 2023-04-23, 11:46:04 | 160 | DEBIT Order#:11985, OrderUsername: chana .... | 11985 |
| 11112 | 2023-04-23, 11:46:04 | -160 | CREDIT Order#:11985, OrderUsername: chana .... | 11985 |

The simple pattern match to fetch orderid from the description is quite simple:

```
    /^.*Order#:(.*?),.*$/
```

But I did not get how to fetch the "orderid" via SQL on 5.5.68-MariaDB
Please help

I tried even adding an additional 'order_id' column, to split the task into 2:

1. get order_id from the text /sorry, did not get how to do that
2. select only duplicated order_id's /sort of know how to do so

*UPDATE:*
3. it is impossible to do so with regexps in MariaDB 5.5
4. it is possible to do so in MySQL 8.0, but it looks like so far nobody knows how to use REGEXP_REPLACE in this context.
5. it is possible to use LOCATE() to find the positions of # and ,, and SUBSTR() to extract the number between them

So the first part of subtask is solved by

```
SELECT id, comment, SUBSTRING(comment, LOCATE('#:', comment) +2,
                 LOCATE(', ', comment)-14) AS order_id
FROM earnings
WHERE (comment LIKE "DEBIT Order%" OR comment LIKE "CREDIT Order%")
```

Second subtask - put result into order_id

```
UPDATE earnings as e1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM SUBSTRING(comment, LOCATE('#:', comment) +2,
                 LOCATE(', ', comment)-14)) AS order_id
FROM earnings
WHERE (comment LIKE "DEBIT Order%" OR comment LIKE "CREDIT Order%")
    ) AS dt 
    ON e1.id= dt.id  set e1.order_id = dt.order_id
```

Comment: Such an old version of MariaDB doesn't have a way to extract from a string using a regexp.

Comment: You'll need to use `LOCATE()` to find the positions of `#` and `,`, and `SUBSTR()` to extract the number between them.

Comment: Please be clear that you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are different products. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products continue to change since then. We all need to think of MariaDB as a distinct product, not a "type of MySQL." It is not compatible with MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar , and how to do a Search and Replace in MySql8, 
/^.*Order#:(.*?),.*$/ REGEXP_REPLACE by what is found within parenthesis?
I found only examples of replace by a distinct word.

Comment: MySQL has `REPLACE_REGEXP()`, but I'm not sure it supports capture groups and back-references.

Comment: @Barmar, it is exactly wjhat I'm searching for ... and  did not find an answer so far.
- I might take the DB dump to a different machine, to MySQL8, but failed to find how to do REGEXP_REPLACE by what was found

Comment: Anyway, LOCATE and SUBSTR looks as a solution! Thank you!!!!